# Can I obtain the client IP from a Mule AJAX inbound endpoint?

Tags: ajax, mule, cometd

With the Mule Ajax connector, is it possible to determine the IP address of the client?

```
<ajax:inbound-endpoint channel="/services/testservice" connector-ref="AjaxConnector" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="AJAX Test"/>
<logger message="#[What Would I put here to get me the client IP]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OMG, the [CometD](https://cometd.org) version used by Mule is older than dinosaurs !

Mule is basically using version 0.x from almost 10 years ago, when CometD was still under the `org.mortbay.cometd` namespace.

Since then, CometD graduated to an independent project under the `org.cometd` namespace.

CometD is currently at version 3.x, and the current APIs do have a way to retrieve the IP address of the client.

Someone with a JIRA login please [file an issue](https://www.mulesoft.org/jira/browse/MULE) to Mulesoft.

Comment: Thanks.  I'll report the issue when I can get my JIRA login to work.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any provision for this in the source code: https://github.com/mulesoft/mule/tree/3.7.2/transports/ajax/src/main/java/org/mule/transport/ajax

All I can see is the addition to the message of a flow var named `ajax.cometd.client`, which contains an instance of `org.cometd.Client` that exposes a `getId()` method. This is probably an opaque ID but it may contain the IP?

So I reckon the answer is no.